# Имеется ли разница в способе образования слов "свиной" и "золотой"?

Tags: словообразование, окончания, морфемный-разбор, суффиксы, словари

В своём 2-томном словообразовательном словаре (М.: Рус. яз., 1990), в разделе "Как пользоваться словарём", Тихонов А. Н. пишет: "Все словообразовательные аффиксы выделены жирным шрифтом".
Теперь к слову "свиной". В слове *свин-**ин**-(а)*, он выделяет жирным шрифтом суффикс *-ин*, а *-а* заключает в скобки, и здесь вопросов не возникает. А вот в слове *свин-**ой*** жирным шрифтом он выделяет *-ой*. Таким образом,  может ли это означать, что *-ой* – это словообразовательный аффикс? И если да, то что это за аффикс, играющий роль в словообразовании? Почему бы ему в этом слове не заключить в скобки *-ой*, а между основой и *-ой* поставить знак нулевого суффикса, как он сделал это в слове *золот(-**Ø**-(ой)*?

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вопрос.  Меня тоже интересует  словообразовательная модель, которая используется в этих словах. Или это разные модели?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NEW**

**Как я понимаю ситуацию:**

Формант ***ОЙ*** является словообразовательным суффиксом для прилагательного ***свиной***, а прилагательное ***золотой*** образуется с помощью **нулевого** суффикса. У этих слов **разные** словообразовательные модели.

1. В Школьном словообразовательном словаре Тихонова 1978 года жирным шрифтом выделен формант ***ОЙ*** в обоих словах, а в новом издании 2022 года жирный шрифт только в слове ***свиной***. Но что в этом удивительного — у этих слов действительно разная семантика. **А какая именно?**
2. Рассмотрим прилагательное ***свиной***.

**СВИНОЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. к Свинья (1 зн.). *С-ое сало. С-ая щетина. С. корм. С. хлев. С-ые котлеты. С-ая тушёнка. С-ая кожа.*

А это для сравнения:

**БАРАНИЙ**, -ья, -ье. 1. к Баран (1 зн.). *Б-ья шкура. Б. жир. Б-ья котлета.*

Очень похожие по семантике слова, а структура у них разная: *свинья — свиной/ой — свин/ого, баран — баран/ий — барань/его.* Окончание ***ОЙ*** в одном слове и суффикс ***ИЙ*** в другом.

Но ведь могло быть и так: ***свинья — свин/ий — свинь/его***. Вполне возможно, что  притяжательный суффикс ***ИЙ*** перешел с суффикс ***ОЙ***, а затем произошло его слияние с окончанием ОЙ.

Но в в любом случае присутствие **звука *Й*** в исходной основе существительного ***свинья*** говорит о том, что притяжательный суффикс в основе **БЫЛ**. Поэтому можно считать, что словообразовательный элемент ***ОЙ*** содержится в окончании ***ОЙ***, именно поэтому Тихонов выделяет его **жирным шрифтом.**

В этом больше **логики**, чем в той схеме, где сначала нужно усекать основу на звук ***Й***, а потом добавлять нулевой суффикс.

Но это всего лишь выбор словообразовательной **модели** в соответствии с современным пониманием вопроса. Интересен **исторический** процесс, но эти сведения нужно искать **в других словарях**, в том числе историко-этимологических.

Прилагательное ***золотой***.

***Золот/о — золот/ой — золот/ого**.* Здесь звука Й в основе нет, поэтому при образовании прилагательного от существительного используется **нулевой** суффикс. Но это опять же современное понимание.

Ведь можно считать, что существительное **перешло** в прилагательное, не меняя своей основы. Но так не принято считать, поэтому говорится о нулевом суффиксе, но почему все же основа **сохранилась**?

**Для сравнения**: *серебро — серебряный, дерево — деревянный*. Но для *золота* эти варианты не подошли, в том числе по **фонетике** все эти слова разные.

Comment: Таким образом, правильно ли будет выделять нулевое окончание в слове свиной?

Comment: Все именно так и делают.  По словообразовательной модели там должен быть  суффикс, поэтому приходится считать его нулевым, а основа будет усеченной.  Тогда слово вписывается в общую систему. Поэтому история с переходом суффикса ОЙ в окончание ОЙ не рассматривается, но это нужно для общего понимания.  (В этом словаре много информации по истории слова http://www.drevoslov.ru/svinjatree )

Comment: Может, кто-то так и делает, но далеко не все.) Очень далеко.) http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1757887-kak-razobrat-po-sostavu-slovo-svinoj.html?ysclid=lo153rcmcd434743917

Comment: Вы туда не ходите, вы сюда ходите)  http://www.drevoslov.ru/svinjatree  А там народ простой, фантазирует много. Мне понравился разбор слова "золотой")

Comment: Иван, а где еще ваши ответы, вы же обещали быть с нами?)  Вас здесь не хватает...  У вас оригинальный (академический) стиль,  он хорошо дополнит нашу разговорную часть форума.

Comment: Вы знаете, я пока присматриваюсь.) И вот что я уже успел заметить. Некоторые участники форума просто спамят вопросами, я даже не знаю, где они берут вдохновение для их постановки.) Таким образом, думается, что было бы неплохо придавать действительно требующим внимания вопросам статус темы дня, например, или же выносить их на обсуждение в чат, в отдельную комнату.)

Comment: Так может показаться, и не все наши участники форума это одобряют. Но не все так просто, вы еще присмотритесь.  Вопросы выглядят нестандартно,  но в то же время они уводят нас от стандарта, заставляют подумать... А вот СТАНДАРТ – это менее заметное, но еще большее зло.  Плохо то, что ответы принимаются быстро, и часто это не самые лучшие (иногда откровенно неправильные) ответы.  С этим надо бороться.  Зато свежий ветер нам окно распахнул...  Так что помогайте нам)

Comment: @Иван Романов, согласен, некоторые участники спамят вопросами, на которые и сами знают ответы. А сами вопросы не имеют ценности.

Comment: Серж, а мне вот приходится иногда подумать, прежде чем ответить на такие вопросы.  А на стандартные и правильные легко найти ответ: в справочник заглянул, правило переписал, примеры подобрал.  Отчего так?

Comment: Ну, может, мы имеем виду с вами разные вопросы.

Comment: Вопросов много, можно выбрать те,  которые действительно заслуживают внимания. Вот сегодня я во второй половине дня отвечала на вопросы с уже  данным ответом, так пришлось убеждать и доказывать свою точку зрения. Потому что на не очень стандартный вопрос был дан непродуманный ответ.  Интересный вопрос о кратком прилагательном (про сытого кота). Простенький, а теорию надо вспомнить.